# No se pudo instalar lapack exitosamente usando Cygwin en Windows

Tags: linux, cmd, prompt

Intenté instalar lapack desde el instalador de Cygwin como normalmente se hace, la instalación me marca como exitosa pero al momento de querer compilar un archivo con la librería me sale el siguiente error:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot fin
d -llapack
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

No sé qué estoy haciendo mal, porque seguí un tutorial al pie de la letra y debería de funcionar. Apreciaría cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Tienes la librería `lapack` instalada (para development)?

Comment: por curiosidad fui a mirar la lista de paquetes. El paquete que debería estar instalado es `liblapack-devel`. Ese es el que tienes instalado? https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/liblapack-devel.html